# Flowbite dark mode issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, flowbite

I'm trying to implement Flowbite dark mode to my application, however facing some strange issues. I followed the docs - [url](https://flowbite.com/docs/customize/dark-mode/), and receiving this error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
```

As I understand it says that one or more values(themeToggleDarkIcon or themeToggleLightIcon) are null or basically not defined. Basically what I did so far - created a component - ThemeSwitcher.vue with content:

```
<template>
  <button id="theme-toggle" type="button"
    class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-700 rounded-lg text-sm p-2.5">
    <svg id="theme-toggle-dark-icon" class="hidden w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M17.293 13.293A8 8 0 016.707 2.707a8.001 8.001 0 1010.586 10.586z"></path>
    </svg>
    <svg id="theme-toggle-light-icon" class="hidden w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path
        d="M10 2a1 1 0 011 1v1a1 1 0 11-2 0V3a1 1 0 011-1zm4 8a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0zm-.464 4.95l.707.707a1 1 0 001.414-1.414l-.707-.707a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414zm2.12-10.607a1 1 0 010 1.414l-.706.707a1 1 0 11-1.414-1.414l.707-.707a1 1 0 011.414 0zM17 11a1 1 0 100-2h-1a1 1 0 100 2h1zm-7 4a1 1 0 011 1v1a1 1 0 11-2 0v-1a1 1 0 011-1zM5.05 6.464A1 1 0 106.465 5.05l-.708-.707a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414l.707.707zm1.414 8.486l-.707.707a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414l.707-.707a1 1 0 011.414 1.414zM4 11a1 1 0 100-2H3a1 1 0 000 2h1z"
        fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
    </svg>
  </button>
</template>

<script>
var themeToggleDarkIcon = document.getElementById('theme-toggle-dark-icon');
var themeToggleLightIcon = document.getElementById('theme-toggle-light-icon');

// Change the icons inside the button based on previous settings
if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme') === 'dark' || (!('color-theme' in localStorage) && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)) {
  themeToggleLightIcon.classList.remove('hidden');
} else {
  themeToggleDarkIcon.classList.remove('hidden');
}

var themeToggleBtn = document.getElementById('theme-toggle');

themeToggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {

  // toggle icons inside button
  themeToggleDarkIcon.classList.toggle('hidden');
  themeToggleLightIcon.classList.toggle('hidden');

  // if set via local storage previously
  if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme')) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme') === 'light') {
      document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
      localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'dark');
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
      localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'light');
    }

    // if NOT set via local storage previously
  } else {
    if (document.documentElement.classList.contains('dark')) {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
      localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'light');
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
      localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'dark');
    }
  }

});
</script>
```

Imported the code to the other component and implemented:

```
<template>
 <section>
  <ThemeSwitcher />
 </section>
</template>

<script>
import ThemeSwitcher from "../../components/ThemeSwitcher.vue";

export default {
  name: "Login",
  components: {
    ThemeSwitcher
  }
}
</script>
```

Seems like everything is done like in docs, but the errors occurs out of nowhere!

Answer (score 1):

That error because access classList before initialize document

My componet for resolve problem

```js
<script setup>
import {onMounted, ref} from "vue";

const themeToggleDarkIcon = ref(null);
const themeToggleLightIcon = ref(null);
const setDarkTheme = () => {
    document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
    localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'dark');
    themeToggleLightIcon.value.classList.remove('hidden');
    themeToggleDarkIcon.value.classList.add('hidden');
}

const setLightTheme = () => {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
    localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'light');
    themeToggleLightIcon.value.classList.add('hidden');
    themeToggleDarkIcon.value.classList.remove('hidden');
}

const toggleTheme = () => {
    // toggle icons inside button
    themeToggleDarkIcon.value.classList.toggle('hidden');
    themeToggleLightIcon.value.classList.toggle('hidden');

    // if set via local storage previously
    if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme')) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme') === 'dark') {
            setLightTheme();
        } else {
            setDarkTheme();
        }

        // if NOT set via local storage previously
    } else {
        if (document.documentElement.classList.contains('dark')) {
            setLightTheme();
        } else {
            setDarkTheme();
        }
    }
}

const initializeTheme = () => {
    const isDarkFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('color-theme') === 'dark';
    const mySystemPreferenceIs = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches ? 'dark' : 'light';

    // Change the icons inside the button based on previous settings
    if (isDarkFromLocalStorage || (!('color-theme' in localStorage) && mySystemPreferenceIs === 'dark')) {
        setDarkTheme();
    } else {
        setLightTheme();
    }
}

onMounted(() => {
    initializeTheme();
})

</script>

<template>
    <button
        id="theme-toggle"
        class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-700 rounded-lg text-sm p-2.5"
        type="button"
        @click="toggleTheme"
    >
        <svg
            id="theme-toggle-dark-icon"
            ref="themeToggleDarkIcon"
            class="hidden w-5 h-5"
            fill="currentColor"
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
            <path d="M17.293 13.293A8 8 0 016.707 2.707a8.001 8.001 0 1010.586 10.586z" />
        </svg>
        <svg
            id="theme-toggle-light-icon"
            ref="themeToggleLightIcon"
            class="hidden w-5 h-5"
            fill="currentColor"
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
            <path
                clip-rule="evenodd"
                d="M10 2a1 1 0 011 1v1a1 1 0 11-2 0V3a1 1 0 011-1zm4 8a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0zm-.464 4.95l.707.707a1 1 0 001.414-1.414l-.707-.707a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414zm2.12-10.607a1 1 0 010 1.414l-.706.707a1 1 0 11-1.414-1.414l.707-.707a1 1 0 011.414 0zM17 11a1 1 0 100-2h-1a1 1 0 100 2h1zm-7 4a1 1 0 011 1v1a1 1 0 11-2 0v-1a1 1 0 011-1zM5.05 6.464A1 1 0 106.465 5.05l-.708-.707a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414l.707.707zm1.414 8.486l-.707.707a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414l.707-.707a1 1 0 011.414 1.414zM4 11a1 1 0 100-2H3a1 1 0 000 2h1z"
                fill-rule="evenodd"
            />
        </svg>
    </button>
</template>
```